# Reference case-control sampling

Tags: logistic, sampling, references, case-control-study

I have to use a case-control sampling design to apply logistic regression. I'm looking for a reference that explains which are the advantages and disadvantages of using a high case-control ratio rather than a lower case-control ratio.  I need it to justify the choice to make since I read here in a discussion that does not exist an optimal case-control ratio.

Could someone suggest a clear and detailed reference?

Comment: @http://stats.stackexchange.com/users/7290/gung could you give me some advices to improve the quality of my question in order to get an answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Alastair Scott](https://www.stat.auckland.ac.nz/showperson.php?firstname=Alastair&surname=Scott) is undoubtedly the primary expert on population-based case-control studies, their design and estimation. Check his page out. A detailed overview of the state of the affairs in the area was delivered by him a few years ago as an invited Waksberg lecture at Statistics Canada Symposium, [see here](http://www.statcan.gc.ca/pub/12-001-x/2006002/article/9546-eng.pdf).